# Copying words from one file to another in cpp

Tags: c++, file

I'm trying to copy words from one file to another in cpp, here's my code :

```
int main()
{

    string from, to;

    cin >> from >> to;

    ifstream ifs(from);

    ofstream ofs(to);

    set<string> words(istream_iterator<string>(ifs), istream_iterator<string>());
    copy(words.begin(), words.end(), ostream_iterator<string>(ofs, "\n"));

    return !ifs.eof() || !ofs;
}
```

this way I get a compilation error :

```
expression must have class type
```

at the line of where I call copy()

If I change the construction of the iterators to the following it works :

```
set<string> words{ istream_iterator<string>{ ifs }, istream_iterator<string>{} };
```

I thought choosing between () and {} when initializing objects in cpp is just a matter of choice but I guess I'm wrong.
Can someone explain this to me ?

Comment: Actually `set<string> words( istream_iterator<string>{ ifs }, istream_iterator<string>{} );` is enough

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first code snippet, the `set<string> words(istream_iterator<string>(ifs), istream_iterator<string>())` line is parsed as a declaration of a function `words` that has two parameters: `istream_iterator<string> ifs` and an unnamed parameter of type `istream_iterator<string>` and returns a `set<string>`. That's why it gives a compilation error. The second one cannot be parsed as a function declaration, so it works properly.

Comment: Why `istream_iterator<string>(ifs)` parsed as a type?

Comment: @Slava The entire expression can be parsed as a declaration of a function with two parameters(`istream_iterator<string> ifs` and `istream_iterator<string>)`, and that's exactly what happens. Why? Well, because C++ standard says so(even though it does not make much sense in this context).

Comment: `istream_iterator<string>(ifs)` should not be parsed as a parameter, that is the problem

Comment: @Slava: Should not? According to whom? Not the C++ standard, surely. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse

Comment: @Slava Why shouldn't it? The parenthesis around `ifs` are just ignored.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley did you read that wiki? `ifstream_iterator()` can be considered as a function returning ifstream_iterator, but `ifstream_iterator(ifs)` cannot.

Comment: So if set has a constructor which gets 2 iterators as parameters I can't create an instance of an object using () ? This is kinda confusing for me because I see examples of constructing objects with () that works @kraskevich

Comment: @dikson231 In general, you can do it. For instance, `set<string> words(iter1, iter2)` works fine if `iter1` and `iter2` are variables' names.

Comment: @dikson231: You certainly can. You just can't do it in a way that would cause the declaration to be ambiguous with a function declaration. You could do: `istream_iterator<string> b(ifs), e; set<string> words(b, e);`

Comment: kraskevich & Benjamin Lindley , thank you both, that concluded it for me :)